# Pseudo Selector problems in Drop Down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 3-level drop down menu and I have **2 issues**:

**Issue 1: Partly solved. See my answer below**
I would like to underline the active selected tag the same blue underline color as when hovering over the other tabs... So if the home page tab is active, it should underline(border-bottom) the home tab until another one is selected...

**Issue 2:**
When hovering over the any of the sub-menu items, it underlines(border-bottom) it like it should, but the underline(border-bottom) is longer than the background of the parent li tag...How do I line them up?

Also, how can I keep 'Services' underlined when I am hovering over its sub-menu items?

**HERE IS MY FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/6aT9W/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a class="first" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="first" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="first" href="#">Services</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Supply &amp; Distribution</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Supply and distribution of industrial and raw materials including timber, machinery, equipment, fuel, technology and other resource.</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Supply of technological products including Information Technology and telecommunication equipment with integrated solutions.</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Procurement &amp; Product Sourcing</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sourcing of industrial products for the industrial, energy and mining sectors.</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Sales and Marketing</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sales, marketing and promotions including brand development strategies, research, demographic targeting.</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="first" href="#">Products</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a>Caskets</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-wrap {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
/*
    BODY
*/
 #page-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 86px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
/* 
    LEVEL ONE
*/
 ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
ul.dropdown li.active a {
    color: #ffa500;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 29px 8px;
    color: #222;
    font- size: 18px;
    font-family:'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}
/* Doesn't work in IE */
 ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover > a, ul.dropdown li > a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #003399;
}
/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/
 ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 230px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
    background: #fafafa;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
 ul.dropdown ul li a {
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
/* 
    LEVEL THREE
*/
 ul.dropdown ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: See my answer below. Found a solution for the first issue, but still not perfect. Updated the JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution for the active tab problem by adding the following JS and CSS:

```
ul.dropdown li.active a{ 
                          color: #000; 
                          border-bottom: 6px solid #003399; 
                          background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown > li').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

But, One problem remains: When clicking on 'Services', all the submenu's are underlined as well. I only want the one underlined and highlighted that is hovered on (for the submenus...)

I guess it has something to do with the .siblings JQuery method...

I Updated my JFiddle

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to change the markup or add a click handler to toggle the class. I see you have li.active class defined. If it's a separate page/url/request for each one of your menu items, have the server make the determination for which top level menu to add the `.active` class to. If you're AJAXing the page content, you should hook into the ajax call to toggle the class on the the correct tab (and remove it from the others). If it's a single-page content (i.e. loaded all at once and just js/jquery/dhtml'ing the appropriate tab to be shown below), that's the place to put the hook.
2. This is tricky... It has to do with the `width: 100%` rule on the `a` elements. If you shrink that down, you can see that the border doesn't overflow as bad. I wouldn't recommend rolling with that because percents are... bad to rely upon. I don't see anything setting the width of the containing `li`, so the box model might just be getting confused.

Ah, I see now you have this rule

```
ul.dropdown ul {
  width: 230px;
```

Combined with the padding for the a

```
ul.dropdown ul li a {
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 8px;
```

It sets the interior width to 230px (100% of the containing li, which is 100% of the containing ul) and then adds padding of 8px left and right, making its total width that the border spans across to be 246px, which doesn't fit. So change the width to 214px, + 8px padding left + 8px padding right = 230px.

3 Change your hovering selectors. Use the `li:hover > a` selector instead of `li > a:hover`

```
ul.dropdown li.hover > a, ul.dropdown li:hover > a {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #003399;
}
```

**Update:** The difference.

`li:hover > a` matches any anchor tag inside a `li` element that is being hovered over. Since the Services & Products `li`'s contain the nested `ul` with `a` inside them, the outer `li` is still being hovered over when you hover over its child elements. And the Services & Products texts are anchors themselves, so they match the rule and get the border.

Updated fiddle with these changes (none of your javascript changes, I can tackle that better if you tell me how you plan to put the content on the page for the menu items): http://jsfiddle.net/6aT9W/5/

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially with the second problem. Will come back to you with the first one later today. Also, what is the diff between li:hover > a AND li > a:hover ?

Comment: Added the explanation to the answer. I'll watch for your feedback on #1. And you're very welcome.